# How to play a Video after others in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

After the vid1 it only loops vid2 but its not playing vid3

```
<video src="vid1.mp4" id="video" autoplay>
    <script>
        var nextVideo = 'vid2.mp4';
        var nextVideo2 = 'vid3.mp4';
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        video.onended = function(){
            video.src = nextVideo;
        }
        nextVideo.onended = function(){
            nextVideo.src = nextVideo2;
        }
        video.volume = 0.2;
    </script>
</video>
```

Comment: `nextVideo` is only a variable with a string value. You'll need to set the `src` of and bind the `onended` event to a video element, like you've done with `video`.

Comment: @RealLuby in case the answer worked for you would you please accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nextVideo `onended` won't have any effect since it is not a `video` element.
Do something like:

```
<video src="vid1.mp4" id="video" autoplay></video>
<script>
    var videos = ['vid2.mp4', 'vid3.mp4'];
    var currentIndex = -1;
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.onended = function(){
        currentIndex++;
        if(currentIndex < videos.length){
            video.src = videos[currentIndex];
        }
    }
    video.volume = 0.2;
</script>
```

This pretty much the right way to dynamically play videos one after another. In case the video does not play call `load()` and `play()` functions after setting the `src`.

```
video.src = videos[currentIndex];
video.load();
video.play();
```